How to add objects to the prefab table at runtime
I'm working with Photon Fusion and I want to add new objects to the prefab table at runtime. I followed the steps in the Advanced Spawning tutorial in the Fusion Manual, but I don't know how to call the method to actually add it.
I tried doing:
runner.Spawn(runner.Prefabs.Load(default, false));

But it says ArgumentException: Invalid prefab id. The method does execute, but it does not work properly.
What do I have to do to create / spawn these new prefabs?

each prefab that is to be spawned across the entire network needs to be a) already present on all client instances ... and b) known to the network by a unique ID. You are simply passing in default as a NetworkPrefabId which probably isn't valid ... What exactly are you trying to achieve here?

I want to users to be able to add custom objects to the game inside the game. So someone would make a package, that would contain multiple objects (GLTF). When the user wants to play that level with these objects, the package would be automatically downloaded from FTP server, unpacked and store on the client PC. This works fine till now. Now i want to also sync that object's transform. But for that I need to call runner.Spawn(), but I can't, because that object needs to be in prefab table.

I think for this kind of self-hosted prefabs you will need to also implement your very own custom service that a) ensures a unique ID to each prefab network wide (e.g. GUID are very unlikely to collide) b) you would spawn a dummy prefab and tell it which of your custom prefab ID it should be loading -> it either already has it and loads it or requests it from your FTP server ....
